# JAVA Random Parameter always returns 0

Tags: java, random, parameters

I am practicing techniques learned by writing a small battle simulator. In my hero class I have methods for storing damage. The methods are:

```
private strike;

public void setStrike(int attack){
    attack = strike;
}

public int retStrike(){
    return strike;
}
```

In my main method, I have a call for a new Random number.

```
    int randomNum = new Random().nextInt(10)+1;

    Mike.setStrike(randomNum);
```

When I call the object Mike and feed the setStrike method in the Hero class's setStrike method, it always returns 0. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I rarely write this methods by hand, use IDE to generate code.

Comment: Shouldn't `strike` be declared as an `int`? Currently, there will be a compile error because it is declared with no type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void setStrike(int attack){
    attack = strike;
}
```

This should be: -

```
public void setStrike(int attack){
    strike = attack;
}
```

You used your assignment opposite. The first assignment has no effect on the private field `strike`.

Comment: @HermesTrismegistus. Happens. You're welcome though. Remember to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the arrow besides it. May be you need to wait before that.

Comment: This is why I love Eclipse's variable highlighting. I would click on `attack` and it will highlight and show me that `attack` is getting changed to `strike` and not the other way around. (PS: Most IDEs have variable highlighting.)